# Crash while declaring Array of class objects

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to declare an array of class objects for my utility. I tried declaring as below but am getting an exception. Not able to understand what am I doing wrong. here is the code section.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct charFreqPair{
public: charFreqPair();
        charFreqPair(char,int);
        ~charFreqPair(){}
        char ch;
        int freq;
};

charFreqPair::charFreqPair(){

}

charFreqPair::charFreqPair(char c , int f){
    ch = c;
    freq = f;
}


int main(int argc , char **argv){
    char *string;
    cout<<"Enter String"<<endl;
    cin>>string;
    charFreqPair array[128] ;
    getch();
}
```

If I run the above code by commenting :
    charFreqPair array[128] ;
everything works fine. But if I run the above code as it is , it's throwing following exception:

> First-chance exception at 0x00d31556 in String1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00d320fd.

I am not able to understand what am I doing wrong in declaring array of class object.

Answer (score 2):

The error is not caused by the array but by the fact that you are using `cin` to save the input into a uninitialized pointer:

```
char *string;
cin>>string;
```

`char *string` is not initialized so dereferencing it causes the exception. Use a `std::string` as you should:

```
std::string;
cin >> string;
```

Comment: You are right, but the problem is if you comment out the charFreqPair array[128] ; and put a cout<<string; it is working ! Why introduction of charFreqPair array[128] causing any difference ?

Comment: Because string is uninitialized so it points to a garbage value which could be anything, so the result is unexpected behavior which is a situation in which you can't assume anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can not just write to a pointer that is not pointing anywhere. No wonder you are getting exceptions, you are writing on random memory.
Allocate your `string` before using it.